# htaccess rewriterule language redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make my new website project multilingual. My idea is to redirect files to an imaginary language folder(like www.domain.com/en/sub/content.php and so on).

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1?lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ /$1?lang=de [L]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ /$1?lang=es [L]
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ /$1?lang=ru [L]
```

It works well for physically existing test files, even down a few folders...

But it doesn't work combined with another rewrite.

To get "www.domain.com/liga.php?whatleague=firstleague&matchday=7" to look like "www.domain.com/firstleague/2013/7/"
I used:

```
RewriteRule ^firstleague/2013/([0-9]+)/?$ /liga.php?whatleague=firstleague&matchday=$1 [L]
```

The redirect alone works fine, BUT the "lang" parameter doesn't get passed on when I add the language folder (www.domain.com/de/firstleague/2013/7/).
I tried it in different order in the htaccess file, but with the same result.

PS: english is not my primary language.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another rule, just add `QSA` flag in you `firstleague` folder:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1?lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ /$1?lang=de [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ /$1?lang=es [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ /$1?lang=ru [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(firstleague)/2013/([0-9]+)/?$ /liga.php?whatleague=$1&matchday=$2 [L,QSA]
```